# EC2 and RDS Authentication?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, rds

I have an EC2 instance running a Node.js Express backend that controls CRUD operations to an RDS instance. I am doing a mobile application client (which I am authenticating users through cognito with the client sdk). What would be the best way to authenticate my mobile app users so that only authenticated users can access my Node.js Express functions running in EC2? Basically looking for something like IAM Lambda authentication (but for this server application, rather than a serverless architecture).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What would be the best way to authenticate my mobile app users so that only authenticated users can access my Node.js Express functions running in EC2

Authenticating with Cognito you shoud be able to get an access token (id token and access token) once the user is authenticated.

The token is to be fetched by the mobile client after the user is authenticated, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognitoidentity/latest/APIReference/API_GetOpenIdToken.html . This token can be sent along every request to the nodejs services. Please note the token has an expiration time and the client needs to get another one when the token is expired.

The token contains user identity, issuer, expiration time and (Cognito) user groups

The services must validate the token (issuer, expiration, signature) and trust the token (or not) based on the validation.

Validation example: https://github.com/kjur/jsrsasign/wiki/Tutorial-for-JWT-verification) in this example the public key is read from a certificate. Amazon provides only the public key properties (e,n) https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/decode-verify-cognito-json-token/, so you will have to complete the public key yourself, example https://github.com/rzcoder/node-rsa

Edit: more detailed clarifications

Comment: Would I need to use the nodejs aws sdk for this? I thought the node sdk was only for client side. My mobile client is the one authorizing the user with Cognito.

Comment: @SteveFreed I've update the answer for more resources and clarifications. Your mobile client will need aws client to get the access/openid token, the nodejs server service needs only to validate the token

Comment: Thank you! That helps a lot